# How can I access a submatrix specified by row and column index vectors from a matrix (2D tensor) in pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Please consider a matrix 
`A= torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]` 
and vectors of indexes 
`ind_1= [0,1]` and `ind_2= [2,3].`

Is it possible to access the top-right sub-matrix of the matrix A (`[[3,4], [3,4]]`) without using any for loops?  Naively using `A[ind_1, ind_2]` merely returns the elements 3 and 4 (the diagonal of the required sub-matrix).

Answer (score 1):

With`A[ind_1,:][:,ind_2]` you can slice first on the rows, then on the columns. This allows accessing also sub-matrices with non-consecutive indices.

Comment: One limitation of this approach is that it creates a copy of the submatrix - thus we can't change the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch tensors support python slicing so you can use `A[:2, 2:]` to access the first two rows and the last two columns as a 2x2 tensor.